# jquery - ajax - problem with update columns one by ones

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i want to update each columns acording by id, when i click on an image, without refresh all the page. my codes just update last ids column when i click each on   images.
index.php:

```
$rzp=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_users_posts` WHERE uid=1");
        while($rw=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rzp)){$id=$rw['id'];
            echo $id;?><img id="up" src="pc3/up.png" alt=""><br>
 <?php }?>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var id = <?php echo $id;?>;

  $(document).on("click","#up",function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
       url: "y2.php",
        data: {id: id},
                async :false
      }).done(function(msg2) {
        alert(msg2);
      });
  });
  });
 </script>
```

y2.php:

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
    mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `tbl_users_posts` SET lik=lik+1 WHERE id='$id'");
```

thanks

Comment: Because you set $id in your while loop, so it will always be the last id set. It would probably be best to find a way to attach that id to your image, possibly as a data attribute which you can then get in your javascript.

Comment: Also, id's must be unique - you're giving each image the same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things immediately wrong here:

- You are re-using `id` values in your HTML, which is invalid.
- Your `var id = ...` JavaScript code always has the last value from your data, and you're explicitly using that every time instead of any value from your HTML element.

Let's simplify.  First, echo your HTML elements to include (1) a `class` to use for triggering the click handler and (2) the ID that the click handler needs:

```
<?php
while($rw=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rzp)){
    $id=$rw['id'];
    echo $id;
?>
    <img class="up" src="pc3/up.png" alt="" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>"><br>
<?php } ?>
```

(Note: There's *probably* a much cleaner way to do that.  I'm attempting to maintain the coding style you currently have, but you should definitely look into cleaner approaches of writing code overall.)

Now you have a bunch of images with (1) a `class` called "up" and (2) a `data-` attribute with the ID you need upon clicking.  Your click handler can now use that information:

```
$(document).on("click", ".up", function() { // use the class as the selector
  var id = $(this).data('id'); // get the data-id value from this specific element
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "y2.php",
    data: {id: id}
  }).done(function(msg2) {
    alert(msg2);
  });
});
```

(Note: I also removed `async: false` because *one should never use `async: false`*.  If there's some reason you think you need to use it, that's a different problem entirely and one that should be addressed as well.)

Comment: thanks it works. now how should i remove alert and function msg2 part?

Comment: @behzad: You can remove the `alert()` by simply removing it.  It's not clear what the issue is there.

Comment: like this? .done(function() {});     there is no need to remove the function?

Comment: @behzad: It's really not clear what you're asking at this point.  You can write your code to do whatever it is you're trying to do.  If you don't want to respond to the AJAX response in any way then, no, you don't need a `.done()` handler.  Though it is recommended to at least examine the response for errors and not assume it worked as desired.

Comment: it works fine thanks. i want to know how should remove that part. i have another question is this a good way to create like button?